# Setting phone number through ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to call to a different document to get the phone number. Unfortunately, it does not appear to be working properly and won't pull the correct phone number. Is there a way I can just set the phone number in the code? Currently my code looks like this:

```
   function setTollNo() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/PURLService.asmx/GetTollNo",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(html) {
                $("[id*=tollNo]").html(html.d);
            },
            error: function() { alert('error'); }
        });
    }
```

Would I be able to put something along the lines of the following?

tollNo = 18005557755

Comment: What do you see if you add alert("response: " + html.d) ?

Comment: This is the response I get with the incorrect number. response1-855-281-5195

Comment: And what do you expect html.d to contain?  Is /PURLService.asmx/GetTollNo some public service with documentation, or an internal service?  Does it expect any parameters?  You aren't passing it anything that I can see.

Comment: It is quite unclear what you are trying to accomplish and why. Why are you using the POST HTTP verb on an RPC called "GetTollNo"? Have you looked at /PURLService.asmx in a browser? Does it tell you what type of arguments it is expecting? If you are able to successfully invoke the webservice, what does the raw JSON look like? Is it even sending back JSON? Is the webservice public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
function setTollNo() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: { tollNo: '18005557755' },
        url: "/PURLService.asmx/GetTollNo",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(html) {
            $("[id*=tollNo]").html(html.d);
        },
        error: function() { alert('error'); }
    });
}
```

Go to the [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) docs and search for "Examples".